# What is the degree of BCD?

Tags: geometry

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uVXE.png)

AB is the tangent of the upper circle and AD is the tangent of the lower one.
What is the degree of BCD?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uVXE.png

Comment: Are angles ABC and ADC supposed to be right?

Comment: And are the chords in the two circles supposed to go through the points where the circles touch the two lines going out from A?

Comment: no, we dont know if abc and adc are right or not.

Comment: Hint: radii are perpendicular to tangents

Comment: they are not radiuses mr Robertson. We are not sure if they are 90

Comment: $BC$ and $CD$ are not radii nor diameters though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: By symmetry, the angle between a chord and the tangent at the end of the chord is the same at both ends of the chord.

So if BA and CD are the tangents at the two ends of BC ...

---

If CB and CD are *not* supposed to be tangents to the circles at C, then you don't have enough information in your drawing to conclude anything. Angle C could be *anything* in that case -- no matter how you choose points B, C, D, you would be able to find an A somewhere such that the angle at A is 80°, and *then* draw small circles tangent to BA and DA that both go through C.

Comment: How do you know CD is tangent?

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh: That's how I interpret your drawing. If it is not, then I don't think you have sufficient information to find the angles.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. Actually I was thinking about 10 hours on this problem

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh: Perhaps post a scan of the full exercise statement?

Comment: Why do you say BA and CD are not supposed to be tangents? CD is not supposed to be tangent but BA is tangent

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh: Sorry, minor typo, fixed.

Comment: How can you prove that in that case that C could be anything? Maybe it remains the same in all drawings

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh: The last paragraph of the answer contains the proof that the angle at C could  be anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Makholm